# Jasper report: Yaxis will displayed 0.0 when upstream and downstream value gap too big

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I got an issue when I process JasperReport.

For example:
I use line chart to displayed upstream and downstream.
the unit of upstream is 'Gbps' and the value of downstream traffic is very small.
[image]

If I make upstream hidden, the yaxis will displayed 0.0

[image: Yaxis label and unit of report]

I try to make the unit and label of yaxis can self-adaption. But I found the data has been processed by jasper, that means I can't get raw data(raw data: 100Kbps processed data: 0.0Gbps)

It is the data I found from line chart object (break point at highcharts function: onChartRedraw)

Data of line chart object:

[image: data of line chart object]

How can I get raw data and how to make the unit self-adaption?
I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: In Highcharts itself you could change label [format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.format) or [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) for yAxis. Is it possible for you to add any of those settings via Jasper report configuration? Data is there, but labels are not precise enough.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I know 'yAxis.labels.formatter' can use expression to make self-adaption, but there are two line chart in report(I have updated the question and uploaded the pic), the issue is not how to make the unit self-adaption each time we run,the problem is if I hidden one of line charts after running report, how to make the unit self-adaption.That's vexing problem. @KacperMadej